# Problem with the javascript script on the google worksheet

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a problem with the script written in `google sheet`.

The script works on the basis of the comparison of the last row from the first sheet, with the cells in the second sheet. If three in a given row agree, it throws a positive value ("in my case, phone number"), and when there is no match I do not inform you about failure in the third sheet.

Now, when a new line is added in the first sheet, nothing happens.

Furthermore, when I change the script and save it, nothing happens.

The question is, what's going on here? Why is not the script with the function automatically working?

Is it possible to create an event that fires when the script is updated. Below is the source code of the example.

```
function MyFunction() 
{
 var One = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
 var Two = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
 
 var j =One.getRange("L1").getValue(); 
 var i =2;
 var b =Two.getRange("K1").getValue();
 var c =1;
 var d =1;
 var e =1;   
 var value1D = One.getRange("D"+j).getValue();
 var value1E = One.getRange("E"+j).getValue();
 var value1F = One.getRange("F"+j).getValue();
 var value1G = One.getRange("G"+j).getValue();      
 var value2D = [];
 var value2E = [];
 var value2F = [];
 var value2G = [];
 var Box = [];
 var BoxD = [];
 var BoxZ;
 var cion;
 var result = [];
 var helpsA = [];
 var helpsB = [];
 var text1 = "Telephone number: ";
 var text2 = "";
 var text3 = "No result";
  
 for(i;i<=b;i++)
 { 
     value2D[i] = Two.getRange("D"+i).getValue();
     value2E[i] = Two.getRange("E"+i).getValue();
     value2F[i] = Two.getRange("F"+i).getValue();
     value2G[i] = Two.getRange("G"+i).getValue();
     
     
     if (((value1D ===value2D[i]) && (value1E ===value2E[i]) && (value1F ===value2F[i]) && (value1G ===value2G[i])) ||
       ((value1D === value2D[i]) && (value1E === value2E[i]) && (value1F === value2F[i])) ||
       ((value1D === value2D[i]) && (value1E === value2E[i]) && (value1G === value2G[i])) ||
       ((value1D === value2D[i]) && (value1F === value2F[i]) && (value1G === value2G[i])) ||
       ((value1E === value2E[i]) && (value1F === value2F[i]) && (value1G === value2G[i])))
      {
        result[c] = text1+Two.getRange("H"+(i)).getValues();
        BoxD[c] = result[c];
        c++;
     }
 
     else if (((value1D !==value2D[i]) && (value1E !==value2E[i])) || ((value1F !==value2F[i]) && (value1G !==value2G[i])) ||
       ((value1D !==value2D[i]) && (value1G !==value2G[i])) || ((value1E !==value2E[i]) && (value1F !==value2F[i])) ||
       ((value1D !==value2D[i]) && (value1F !==value2F[i])) || ((value1E !==value2E[i]) && (value1G !==value2G[i])))
    {
      BoxZ = text3;
    }
    else
    {
      BoxD[c] = "Error!";
    }
   
   
    if((BoxD[1]===undefined) || (BoxD[1]===null))
    {
       cion = BoxZ;
    }
    else if(BoxD[1])
    {
       cion = BoxD[1];
    }
    else
    {
       cion = "Error!";
    }
 }//end for
     return cion;
};
```

Comment: If you change the function name to `onEdit` it will get fired every time you change a sheet. Read up on this and you can decide in code which change events you want to respond to.

Comment: @RadVoltron How are you going with your Google scripts problem? Worked it out, or still needing help?